# How to save json array in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to save json array in mysql, but getting error. First, i had tried to save it as a string
using implode function. But not getting same string while fetch data. Now trying to save json string as it is.So that i can fetch it easily.This is json string

```
{"us_id":"1","stu_id":"6","class_id":"3","req_x":[
  { "u_id":"1", "u_details":"testing user", "charges":"12.50"},
  { "u_id":"2", "u_details":"testing user 2", "charges":"10.50" },
  { "u_id":"3", "u_details":"testing user 3", "charges":"9.50" }
]}
```

And i need to save req_x field in diff column in db

```
$req_x = '[
  { "u_id":"1", "u_details":"testing user", "charges":"12.50"},
  { "u_id":"2", "u_details":"testing user 2", "charges":"10.50" },
  { "u_id":"3", "u_details":"testing user 3", "charges":"9.50" }
]';
```

And this is code saving json string using implode

```
$req_dets= implode("&",array_map(function($a) {return implode("|",$a);},$req_x));
```

Now i am trying to save it using simply

```
json_decode($req_x)
```

But it's not working. Returns error
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string array given

Comment: Did you checked using `dd($req_x)` for that variable. What you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting with this JSONstring

```
$start = 
'{   "us_id":"1",
    "stu_id":"6",
    "class_id":"3",
    "req_x":[
                { "u_id":"1", "u_details":"testing user", "charges":"12.50"},
                { "u_id":"2", "u_details":"testing user 2", "charges":"10.50" },
                { "u_id":"3", "u_details":"testing user 3", "charges":"9.50" }
            ]
}';
```

And you only want to save the `req_x` array to the database....

```
$obj = json_decode($start);
$arr = $obj->req_x;
// make a json string of that
$json_req_x = json_encode($arr);

echo $json_req_x;
```

RESULT is a JSONString

```
[
    {"u_id":"1","u_details":"testing user","charges":"12.50"},
    {"u_id":"2","u_details":"testing user 2","charges":"10.50"},
    {"u_id":"3","u_details":"testing user 3","charges":"9.50"}
]
```

Now you can put the string `$json_req_x` into your database using an INSERT or UPDATE as you would with any other column.

Comment: yes it's saving but when i fetch data it's showing  slash before and after every column e.g  {/"u_id/":/"1/",/"u_details/":/"testing user/","/charges/":/"12.50/"}

Answer (score -1):

What is the data type for that column? To store JSON data try changing the column data type to JSON.

Comment: Share your code to explain your solution better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).